# Is there a difference between "const int" and "int" in an array declaration?

Tags: c++, arrays, integer, constants

Is there any difference between:

```
int size = 10000;
```

and

```
const int size = 10000;
```

This code deals with arrays where the `size` variable name would go into the array as `array[size]`.

How I have used this in my code:

```
int main() {
    int size = 50000; // here is where I had const before
    int * items;
    items = new int [size];
    
    //random array for bubbleSort
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        items[i] = rand();
    }
    
    clock_t start, end;
    assert((start = clock()) != -1);
    sort1(items, size); //bubbleSort
    end = clock();
    cout << "bubbleSort(random): " << (double)(end - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds" << endl;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`const` has a number of effects in C++.

The first and most obvious is that it means a value is read-only. Expanding on your example a little:

```
int size = 10000;

const int size2 = 10000;

int main() { 
    size = 1; // fine
    size2 = 2; // won't compile
}
```

In this case, that means `size2` really is a constant. The C++ standard has some special language to allow a compiler to eliminate a `const`-qualified variable and just treat it as a value as long as you only use it in ways that don't require it to have an address.

Another effect is that a const-qualified value has the potential to be used as a constant expression, so it can be used in a few ways that non-constant expressions can't, such as defining the size of an array<sup>1</sup> (but note that you rarely want to use arrays in C++ anyway--`std::vector` is usually preferred).

Another effect (in C++, but not C) is that defining a variable as `const` also makes it `static`, so in your case (where the variables appear to be defined outside any function) the unqualified variable is global so it could be seen from another translation unit (source file) with an appropriate `extern` declaration. The `const` variable could not be.

Note that when `const` applies via a pointer or reference, it really does mean "read-only", not `constant". For example, given a function like:

```
int foo(int const &bar);
```

...code inside of `foo` can't write to whatever `bar` refers to, *but* `bar` could be bound to a non-const variable, so other code referring to it directly could modify it. Given multithreading, it's even possible for code inside `foo` to read two (or more) different values from `bar`, even though that code in `foo` can't modify `bar` itself.

Note that `const` can also be apply to an entire `class`, such as in a `const`-qualified member function:

```
struct foo {
    int i;

    int bar() const {
        // i = 2; // won't compile
        return 1;
    }
};
```

This basically changes the type of `this` from `foo * const` to `foo const * const`, so you can't write to any part of `foo` in that member function (except by casting away the `const`, which you really shouldn't do).

There is also a way to side-step that restriction: in a few cases, a class will do things like caching (aka memoizing) a value. For example, if it has a value that's expensive to calculate, it might store that value after its calculated, so it won't have to be re-calculated if it's requested again. In this case, you can mark that variable as `mutable`, which allows it to be modified even when accessed via a pointer to `const` (or reference to `const`).

```
struct foo {
    mutable int i;

    int bar() const {
        // i = 2; // compiles without problem
        return 1;
    }
};
```

---

<sup>1. Note that some compilers, especially gcc, have an extension that allows you to define non-global arrays with sizes that aren't constants though, so this can be a somewhat misleading criterion. Although this is an extension in C++, it's a standard part of C (from C99 onward).</sup>

Answer (score 4):

The difference is the "const" keyword. In your first example, "size" is not a constant. This allows the size to be redefined and changed. But because this is not a constant it is also not possible to define it as the size of an array. If you were to use your first example it would not compile.

Your second example uses the "const" keyword. With this once the variable is declared, the value cannot be changed. This makes it possible for you to use it to define an array then.

See the code example too.

```
// Will not work because not const
int size = 10000;
int myArray[ size ];

// Will work because const
const int size = 10000;
int myArray[ size ];
```

Comment: My program does still compile and produces the same results as if I use the const keyword which is what confuses me. I will add a bigger portion of my code above.

Comment: Even if it is not `const`, it still compiles. It won't compile only if  `size` was not initialized with a certain value. And this is question is a duplicate of many other question. OP didn't put any research efforts.

Comment: None of the other posts helped me to understand why my program still runs exactly the same way when I use const and when I don't use const.

Comment: @tyler Then edit your questions' title. You are not asking for the explicit difference, you would want to ask for a "wierd" behavior

Comment: @Tyler, your program compiles because you do not use array, but allocate memory dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

From cppreference:

> an object whose type is const-qualified, or a non-mutable subobject of a const object. Such object cannot be modified: attempt to do so directly is a compile-time error, and attempt to do so indirectly (e.g., by modifying the const object through a reference or pointer to non-const type) results in undefined behavior.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv